# Python Scrapy Непонятное поведение селекторов

Tags: python, xpath, scrapy

Пытаюсь парсить таблицы со страницы ([например](https://www.obi.ru/paroochistiteli/paroochistitel-karcher-sc-2-deluxe-easyfix-1500-vt/p/4399226)). Конкретно на этой странице у первой таблицы нет заголовка, а у второй и третьей заголовок есть (Размеры и вес (брутто), Дополнительная информация).

Пусть SelectorList будет таким:

```
tables = response.xpath('//section[@class="collapse in desc"]'+
                        '//table[@class="c-datalist c-datalist--33"]')
```

Теперь, если я хочу взять заголовок первой таблицы:

```
tables[0].xpath('//th[@class="h5"]')
```

получаю

```
['<th class="h5">Разме...утто)</th>', '<th class="h5">Допол...мация</th>']
```

Затем хочу взять заголовок второй таблицы

```
tables[1].xpath('//th[@class="h5"]')
```

и получаю то же самое

```
['<th class="h5">Разме...утто)</th>', '<th class="h5">Допол...мация</th>']
```

Вопрос - почему результаты в первом и втором случае такие, какие есть, а не пустой список в первом случае и заголовок второй таблицы во втором случае?

Answer (score 0):

Относительный xpath определяется через ".". В моем случае

```
tables[1].xpath('.//th[@class="h5"]')
```